# How to change attribute type <TRUE/FALSE> in xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I have to change xml attribute value for 'Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations' toTRUE to FALSE.
Here, the xml looks like

```
    <BusinessRules>
    <BusinessRule>
        <Type>All_NoEmptyRequiredProperty</Type>
        <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">TRUE</Enabled>
    </BusinessRule>
    <BusinessRule>
        <Type>All_CheckStringLength</Type>
        <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">TRUE</Enabled>
    </BusinessRule>
    <BusinessRule>
<BusinessRule>
    <Type>Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations</Type>
    <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">TRUE</Enabled>
</BusinessRule> 
<BusinessRule>
  <Type>ProdOff_AllowAccountPOCurrencyMismatch</Type>
  <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">FALSE</Enabled>
</BusinessRule>
<!-- Following business rule was added for FEAT-147 -->
<BusinessRule>
  <Type>ProdOff_AllowMultiplePISubscriptionRCNRC</Type>
  <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">FALSE</Enabled>
</BusinessRule>
<!-- Following business rule was added for CORE-10776 -->
<BusinessRule>
  <Type>ImmediateSubscriptionTermination</Type>
  <Enabled ptype="BOOLEAN">FALSE</Enabled>
</BusinessRule>
```

Can anybody help me using c# I tried with below code

```
     XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
  xml.Load("R:\\config\\ProductCatalog\\PCConfig.xml");


  XmlNodeList nodes = xml.SelectNodes("//BusinessRule");
  //XmlNodeList type = xml.SelectNodes("//Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations");
  foreach (XmlElement element in nodes)
    {

      element.SelectSingleNode("Type").InnerText = "Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations";

    }
    xml.Save("R:\\config\\ProductCatalog\\PCConfig.xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like this

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load(YourXMLFile);
xdc.Descendants("BusinessRule")
   .LastOrDefault()
   .Descendants("Enabled")
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Value = "False";
xdc.Save(YourXMLFile);
```

or

```
XDocument xdc = XDocument.Load(YourXMLFile);    
xdc.Descendants("BusinessRule")
   .Where(x => x.Descendants("Type")
                .FirstOrDefault()
                .Value == "Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations"
          )
   .Descendants("Enabled")
   .FirstOrDefault()
   .Value = "False";
```

Comment: I am getting error in Where condition. <System.Xml.Linq.Element> doesn't contain a defination for 'where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: <System.Xml.Linq.Element> doesn't contain a defination for 'where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: I think you need to add the namespace `using System.Linq` at the top of the cs file.

Comment: Hi @Vital if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XElement element = xml.Root.Elements("BusinessRule").Where(xElement => xElement.Element("Type").Value == "Hierarchy_RestrictedOperations").FirstOrDefault();

        if(element != null)
        {
            element.Element("Enabled").Value = "FALSE";
        }

        xml.Save("R:\\config\\ProductCatalog\\PCConfig.xml");
```

Make sure that the tags of the xml file are all correct.
Hope this was useful.

Comment: I am getting error in Where condition. <System.Xml.Linq.Element> doesn't contain a defination for 'where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type.

Comment: add "using System.Linq;"

Comment: Added both using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Linq;

Comment: No, it's  system.Linq

Comment: and make sure that your .net framework is 3.5 or higher, and the name space is just "System.Linq", check this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq(v=vs.111).aspx

Comment: Sure. Thank you . I will try and let you know.